# Discord.py-rewrite wait_for() how do i use?

Tags: python, discord.py

I can not really use `wait_if ()` the way I want it, can anyone explain how to use `wait_for ('message')` and `wait_for ('reaction')`, only by the user of the command? (message translated by Google Translate, forgive me for any error...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for) takes a `check` argument that is a function that takes the arguments of the event you're waiting for and determines whether or not that is the event you're waiting for.

For example, the [`on_message` event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.on_message)  takes a `message` argument, so if we wanted to check the author of a message we could do:

```
msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
```

to see that the new message comes from the same person who invoked the currently running command.

If we wanted to send a message to the next person to react with a certain emoji, we could do

```
reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', 
                                       check=lambda reaction, user: reaction.emoji == '')
await user.send(" to you too!")
```