# Checks For Reactions Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So I want to make a text game that edits the character every time the author who called the command reacts. My code so far for adding reactions:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send('Hi')
    up = '⬆'
    down = '⬇'
    left = '⬅'
    right = '➡'
    await msg.add_reaction(up)
    await msg.add_reaction(down)
    await msg.add_reaction(left)
    await msg.add_reaction(right)
```

This adds the up arrow, down arrow, left arrow, and right arrow to the message "Hi". I want to see if someone clicked on the arrow and if that someone is the author of the command. I have no idea how to get if the author of the command clicked on the arrow reaction. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out `wait_for()` Here is an example here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52571844/discord-py-rewrite-wait-for-how-do-i-use

Comment: Wait, they are doing if you add an reaction, bot if you click an reaction....

Comment: So do i do reaction_click instead of reaction_add

Comment: That doesn't seem to work......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're waiting for a reaction, use [`wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) with the `reaction_add` event as the positional argument.

To limit it to the invoker, you can create a check and pass it into the `check` kwarg of `wait_for()`. The check would take in two arguments and you only need to compare if `ctx.author` is the same as the check author.

There is an example for `wait_for()` in the documentation

References: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for

Comment: I am waiting for the author to click on the reaction the bot made,

Comment: You would still use the reaction_add event, you can limit who can use it in the check

Comment: but doesn't reaction_add wait for someone to add an reaction, not click on an reaction?

Comment: `reaction_add` waits for a reaction to be added. Clicking on a reaction is still adding a reaction because you're adding a react onto an existing reaction

Comment: Wait, how do you reset an reaction so everyone who clicked on it will be erased except for you? I know this isn't on the question, but it would be great if u helped!

Comment: You can reset reactions using [Message.clear_reactions()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=clear#discord.Message.clear_reactions) then re-reacting on the bot.